# Boot time with graphics card driver

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am new to Linux. My laptop came with ubuntu 12.04, i upgraded it to 14.04. The problem is when i use the graphics card driver, it takes up about 25 seconds more than when i boot up with nouveau driver, there is a black empty screen before the splash screen which takes up most of the time. My graphics card is nvidia 820m and the driver i use is nVidia GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]. My laptop is dell inspiron 3542. Is this normal behavior, does using the graphics driver increase boot time?

I also want to ask if boot time of 14.04 is greater than that of 12.04 because even without using the graphics driver the boot time of 14.04 is about 10-15 seconds greater than 12.04 on my system.
This is annoying because i know that the system can go faster but i dont know why it is taking this much time.

I used bootchart to determine the boot times. Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/PLPu7agY) to output of dmesg.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior as the NVIDIA kernel driver has to be loaded additionally.

Boot time depends on many different things : hardware, init system, kernel etc.

So there is nothing you should worry about - just enjoy ubuntu experience !

Comment: so should it take more than a minute to boot? there must be something that can be done to lower the time.

Comment: @doctorsherlock : Yes, it can take more than a minute. I have three machines and all of them have different boot times, one of them needs nearly 2 minutes. What you can do to decrease boot time is to replace your HDD with a SSD - in case you don't have one already. In the end it is not that important how fast a computer boots, more important is that the PC runs smoothly. Hope this helped you !